# How to get the "location" header with jQuery's $.post function?

Tags: jquery, post, header, location

I'm trying to create a pop up box (with jQuery) that can handle forms, and for the most part, I have it all working. The only issue that I have is that on a successful login and/or register, PHP sends a header location to redirect to the user to their "home", and it creates an endless loop of redirects with in the div that I loaded the form.

How would I go about reading if there was a `location` header sent on the post request, and then to get the actual URL that is being sent as the new `location`?

This is what I have tried so far (among other things):

```
$('.register').live('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var form_data = $(this).serialize() + '&register=register&js=true';

    $.post(site_path + '/register', form_data, function(data, text, xhr) {

        alert(xhr.getResponseHeader("Location"));

        // $('.overlay_container').html(data);

    });

});
```

Not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong, but as far as I know, something along those lines should work. I also tried doing this with a plain AJAX post request to no expected result.

Just to note, there wont always be a location header sent; only when someone successfully logs in, registers, etc.

Ideally, this is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
$('.register').live('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var form_data = $(this).serialize() + '&register=register&js=true';

    $.post(site_path + '/register', form_data, function(data, text, xhr) {

        var header_location = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");

        if(header_location == null) {

            $('.overlay_container').html(data);

        }else{

            window.location = header_location;

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: You should avoid using `jQuery.live()` at all times! Use `.on()`. If `.on()` is not available within your version of jQuery, use `.delegate()`.

Comment: @Tadeck Originally I had tried to use `.on()`, however it doesn't seem to work. I'm using 1.7.1 off of Google's CDN. As far as I know, it should be included in there (as of 1.7), but it fails to work. http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: `.on()` **is included since 1.7** and it definitely works. Moreover, `.on()` can fully replace both `.live()` and `.delegate()`, is superior to them and is meant to replace them. It seems you are using it incorrectly or you are making some other mistake.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't I just replace `.live()` with `.on()`? I'm trying to do use this function on HTML that loaded in via `.load()`. Oddly enough, it isn't working when I do what I described above, where as `.live()` does work.

Comment: Yes, you should definitely replace `.live()` with `.on()`, but do it correctly (as mentioned by me above). When it comes to your problem, is the success callback even executed? In other words: is the `var header_location = ...` part reached by your script? I believe no, but please confirm it or deny.

Comment: @Tadeck Yes, it is reaching that variable. I can change it to anything else (i.e. `Content-Type`, `Content-Length`, etc), and it works (when I make it send as an alert). It just seems to always return `null` when asking for `Location`, even when PHP sends a `Location` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far a I am aware, you can not actually read a `Location` header as JavaScript follows it until they stop, and then sends the `headers` back, meaning that I get the headers of the destination page, and not the page that was initially posted to.

Therefore, I have edited my redirect function that I have in my PHP script to send a custom header if the page was requested using JavaScript (or jQuery).

```
public function redirect($redirect = NULL) {

    global $_CONFIG;

    if($_POST['js'] == 'true') {

        exit(header('Redirect: ' . $_CONFIG['site']['path'] . '/' . $redirect));

    }else{

        exit(header('Location: ' . $_CONFIG['site']['path'] . '/' . $redirect));

    }

}
```

That way I can read if the a redirect was actually sent, and handle it properly on the JavaScript (jQuery) end of things.

Here's what the final result looks like:

```
$('.popup').on('submit', '.register', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var action = $(this).attr('action'), form_data = $(this).serialize() + '&register=register&js=true';

    $.post(action, form_data, function(data, text, xhr) {

        var header_location = xhr.getResponseHeader('Redirect');

        if(header_location == null) {

            $('.overlay_container').html(data);

        }else{

            window.location = header_location;

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: It is not the case in my experience that anything with a Location header is automatically followed by the browser. I just did a test and received the first level response.